# Regular expression for any domain followed by a folder

Tags: regex

I have the following regular expression which basically returns *.domain.com/*

```
^[0-9a-zA-Z_\-.]{1,256}\.domain\.com/
```

I am looking to change the expression so that it returns any domain with a dot com extension that is followed by /js can anyone tell me how I can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
(?:http:\/\/)(.*?\.com(?=\/js\/))
```

If you can tell your regex processor to return capture group #1, you'll get any domain preceded by `http://` and followed by `/js/`.

Otherwise (i.e. using this expression as a stand-alone), you'll get the domain *including* the `http://`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
^([\w\d_\-]+[\.]?[\w\d\-_]+)+\.com\/js$
```